# Creating a URL Redirect

Tags: php, html

So I have a stupid marketing team that gave 1 million people a URL to our site and it's misspelled. How do I take the incoming URL and redirect it to the correct URL? I'm using Wordpress site, and we're using a redirection plugin but it's causing a ton of problems so I want to find out how to manually do this if possible.

Any gurus would like to help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you show the misspelled and the intended URL?

Comment: it would be domain.com/whatever and I need to redirect that to domain.com/Whatever. The names aren't important as the plugin I'm using does the same thing for us, I just need to know how to manually do it

Comment: Maybe you can mod_rewrite it in .htaccess?

Answer (score 5):

In .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^MisspelledURL$ CorrectURL [R=301,L]
```

Comment: You should add a 301 "Moved Permanently" status code though..

Comment: @poke, I added that to the answer.

Comment: so it would be RewriteRule ^http://domain.com/bad$ http://domain.com/Bad [R=301,L] - with Bad being the actual page that i am trying to redirect TO?

Comment: Yes, but if pages are on the same domain, you can just do `RewriteRule ^bad$ /Bad [R=301,L]`.  domain.com/bad will redirect to domain.com/Bad

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have access to mod_rewrite (Rocket's answer), you could also send the header by simply adding a script that does so to the misspelled directory. For example with php:

```
<?php
header( 'HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently' );
header( 'Location: http://domain.com/Whatever' );
exit;
?>
```

Comment: would this have to be on the actual page? Problem is I'm using Wordpress which creates pages dynamically.

Comment: You simply add a file to the misnamed directory that is called automatically (usually index.php). I'm not sure if that works with Wordpress, as that usually already uses mod_rewrite to rewrite every single url..

Answer (score 2):

If it's a simple URL and you don't need to fix up query parameters, you could use a simple

```
RedirectPermanent /bad/URL/here http://example.com/proper/url/here
```

in your httpd.conf. That'll send a 301 code as well

Answer (score -2):

You could forget all of this and just do a Domain forward in DNS. If you have control of the current domain modify the DNS Zone.
BadDomain.com  14400 IN CNAME GoodDomain.com.

Adding scripts and php or htAccess all mean you have to be hosting the bad domain first. You can get a hold of your DNS Record for the good record and add the redirect & your done.